# How to Show/hide a select box if a value in another select box is chosen

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have two select boxes on a page, coded as follows:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SearchList, htmlAttributes: new {@class = "control-label col-md-2"})
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SearchListId, Model.SearchList, "Select Search Type", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label input-width-xlarge", id = "SearchList" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SearchListId, "", new {@class = "text-danger"})
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.GroupSortTypes, htmlAttributes: new {@class = "control-label col-md-2"})
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.GroupSortId, Model.GroupSortTypes, "Select Group Sort", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label input-width-xlarge", id = "GroupSortTypes"})
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.GroupSortId, "", new {@class = "text-danger"})
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I make the second select box (GroupSort) visible only when a particular option is chosen in the first? In this case it would be option three out of five options.

Thanks!

Comment: can't found javascript code ?

Comment: `$(#'SearchListId').change(function() { // do something based on $(this).val() })`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First add a class `hide` to your 2nd dropdown and write below code in your js file

```
$(document).on('change','#SearchList',function(){
       var optionSelected = $("option:selected", this);// Use this if only needed
       var valueSelected = this.value;
       var textSelected = this.text;//Use any of the above either value or text in your if condition
       if(valueSelected=="Your Option")
       {
            $("#GroupSortTypes").removeClass("hide");
       }
       else
       {
            $("#GroupSortTypes").addClass("hide");
       }
});
```